# What does it mean "return !! userId"

Tags: javascript

In Meteor tutorial project Microscope there is row with "!!" operator

```
Posts.allow({
  insert: function(userId, doc) {
  return !! userId; 
 }
});
```

What does it mean?

Comment: The principle behind this is called type casting and it's already covered by many questions.

Answer (score 3):

It returns `userId` as a `boolean`

Answer (score 3):

It's a `boolean` cast, from a `fasly` or `truethy` value to `false` or `true` respectively.

You might see:

```
var string = ""; // empty string is falsy
var bool = !!string; // false
```

---

`falsy` by the way means that it follows: `myvar == false` as opposed to `false` which follows: `myvar === false` (triple comparison).

Similarly `truethy` is `myvar == true`.

Answer (score 2):

`!!userId` is the same as `Boolean(userId)`.

Answer (score 1):

The `!` operator inverts a boolean, so by inverting a value two times, you get the same boolean. So `true === !!true`.

This often is used to convert a value into a boolean, as `!` is guaranteed to return a boolean.